# ¿Como guardar respuesta de una API con angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rest, get

Llevo horas tratando de solucionar esto, trato de guardar la respuesta de una api que esta en formato json, me muestra la respuesta por consola al momento de llamar a la función del servicio, pero no me guarda la respuesta en la variable this.datos , al momento de mostrarla por consola me arroja undefined cuando imprimo la variable luego de haber llamado al servicio y "guardado" la respuesta en datos.

**Component**

```js
constructor(private activedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private dispositivo:DispositivosService) {
    this.id=this.activedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    this.getInfo();
    console.log(this.datos);
  }
  getInfo(){
    this.dispositivo.getInfo(this.id).subscribe(
      res =>{
        console.log(res);
        this.datos=res;
      },
      err=>console.log(err)
    )
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/internal/Observable";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DispositivosService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  API_URI='http://localhost:3000';

  getDispositivo(usuario:number){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/dispositivos/${usuario}`);
  }
  getInfo(dispositivo:number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/datos/${dispositivo}`);
  }

}
```

**Consola**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se debe a la asincronía, me explico:

1. Al ejecutarse el constructor, llama a getInfo().
2. Dentro de getInfo se hace una petición asíncrona mediante http.get. Las peticiones asíncronas no bloquean la ejecución de la aplicación.
3. El código se sigue ejecutando aunque no haya recibido respuesta de la petición http.get. Por lo tanto, se acaba el método getInfo, vuelve al constructor y lanza el console.log(this.datos) sin haber recibido ninguna respuesta todavía, por lo que es undefined.
4. Recibimos respuesta http a nuestra petición de getInfo, lo que acciona el código del subscribe del http.get.
5. Dentro del subscribe de http.get se guarda la respuesta y hace el console.log, esta vez sí, con datos.

Answer (score 0):

Es por el flujo de la aplicación, el constructor se ejecuta, llama a la función getInfo(), pero no espera a recibir respuesta y por eso te sale Undefined. Una vez ya acaba dicha función te salta el nuevo console.log que tienes colocado con sus datos recibidos.